# Symfony detect user timezone

Tags: php, symfony, timezone, symfony5

I am trying to log the timezone of the user. So on login I get their `Session` and `Request` objects and try to get it via

```
$request->request?->get('_timezone')
```

But this key doesn't exist.

Using Symfony 5, how can I get to the user timezone reliably?

Comment: To my knowledge, browsers don't share this information with the servers, so Symfony can't access it. You may get it from Javascript though: [Getting the client's time zone (and offset) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-time-zone-and-offset-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. At least not directly.

In the server, there is no information about the user's timezone.

You could try getting it by:

- Getting the user's IP from the request (not 100% reliable)
- Geolocating the IP address (not 100% reliable)
- Getting the timezone information from the location information.

You can find information about how to perform each of these steps in many places.

But there is no `$request->getTimeZone()`, because a request does not have a timezone, and that information is not forwarded with the request automatically. If you capture it in the frontend (e.g. [Getting the client's time zone (and offset) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-time-zone-and-offset-in-javascript)), then you could make it part of the request data.